# Export data frame (pandas) to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I'm facing a issue  to export a dataframe from pandas to excel
The dataframe is called `key_claims_wear`
I wrote the following script to try to accomplish that:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('key.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
key_claims_wear.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index='False')
writer.save()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 175:     
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Anyone can help with that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure but can you try passing `encoding='utf-8'` or `'utf-16'` to `to_excel`

Comment: how do I do it on my script?

Comment: `key_claims_wear.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index='False', encoding='utf-8')` I'm not sure if this will solve your issue though

Comment: It didnt work, but thank you anayway @EdChum

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this as first line of your python file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```